# Update many sub of sub-document array using $set / $push

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, express, mongoose

Following is the Sample Workspace document.I want to update box positions when we drag and drop at front end.

```
{
"_id": ObjectId("5eaa9b7c87e99ef2430a320b"),
"logo": {
    "url": ".../../../assets/logo/dsdsds.png",
    "name": "testUpload"
},
"name": "My World",
"sections": [{
        "box": [{
                "_id": ObjectId("5da87b33502d6c634b3aa7ce"),
                "name": "Meran To",
                "position": 0
            },
            {
                "_id": ObjectId("5da87b33502d6c7d873aa7d0"),
                "name": "Documentation",
                "position": 2
            },
            {
                "_id": ObjectId("5da87b33502d6cdbb93aa7cf"),
                "name": "File Manager Upload File Drive",
                "position": 1
            },
            {
                "_id": ObjectId("5da87b33502d6c276a3aa7cd"),
                "name": "File Manager Upload File Drive",
                "position": 1
            }
        ],
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Simplicity",
        "description": "Follow your barriers"
    },
    {
        "box": [],
        "id": 2,
        "title": "xfxdfxcx 34",
        "description": "sdsdsd sfsfsd ewrewrewre"
    }
]
}
```

I send the updated positions from front-end to back-end via API, in an array as shown below.

```
[
 {
   "id": "5da87b33502d6c634b3aa7ce",
   "position": 0
 }, {
   "id": "5da87b33502d6c7d873aa7d0",
   "position": 1
 }, {
   "id": "5da87b33502d6cdbb93aa7cf",
   "position": 2
 }, {
   "id": "5da87b33502d6c276a3aa7cd",
   "position": 3
}]
```

I am currently updating DB using the below code

```
for (const el of req.body) {
  await this.model.updateOne({
    _id: req.params.workspaceId,
    sections: {
        $elemMatch: {
            id: req.params.sectionId
        }
    },
    'sections.box': {
        $elemMatch: {
            _id: el.id
        }
    },
  }, {
    $set: {
        'sections.$[outer].box.$[inner].position': el.position
    }
  }, {
    arrayFilters: [{
        'outer.id': req.params.sectionId
    }, {
        'inner._id': el.id
    }],
    upsert: false,
  });
}
```

But this is not the best method, it hits DB multiple times.
so I need to optimize this code with mongoose query itself.
May be using $set / $push.I don't know any exact methods.

So basically we need to remove the external for loop and make it work with mongoose itself.This is my requirement.

Thanks in advance for all the support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 methods for doing it.

1. bulkWrite

   ```
   const bulkOps = [];
   req.body.forEach((el) => {
       const upsertDoc = {
           updateOne: {
               filter: {
                 _id: req.params.workspaceId,
                 sections: {
                   $elemMatch: {
                     id: req.params.sectionId
                   }
                 },
                'sections.box': {
                   $elemMatch: {
                     _id: el.id
                 }
              },
          },
          update: {
            $set: {
               'sections.$[outer].box.$[inner].position': el.position
            }
          },
          arrayFilters: [{
            'outer.id': req.params.sectionId
          }, {
           'inner._id': el.id
          }],
          upsert: false,
       }
     };

     bulkOps.push(upsertDoc);
   });

   const result = await this.model.collection.bulkWrite(bulkOps);
   ```
2. bulkUpdate

   ```
    const bulkUpdate = this.model.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
    req.body.forEach((el) => {
      bulkUpdate.find({
            _id: req.params.workspaceId,
            sections: { $elemMatch: { id: req.params.sectionId } },
            'sections.box': { $elemMatch: { _id: el.id } },
        }).arrayFilters([{ 'outer.id': req.params.sectionId }, { 'inner._id': el.id }])
        .updateOne({ $set: { 'sections.$[outer].box.$[inner].position': el.position } 
      });
    });
    await bulkUpdate.execute();
   ```